# SonarQube and LDAP - Case sensitive logins

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I am checking SonarQube 5.4 and the latest LDAP plugin 1.5.1. There are however a couple of issues.

First. My AD account is majcicam. If I log in with it, it is correctly shown in the users list. However if I login with MajcicaM (note capital letters) another additional user is added to the list:

[image]

As you can see from the attached image. For every login that I do make, seems it is treated as case sensitive and thinks of it as a different user.

Second thing. Once I assign a group to my user, on the next login those settings are gone. Seems that they are not persisted.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Are my settings messed up?

Thanks

Mario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No bugs here, just some subtleties about [LDAP Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) configuration and behaviour. :)

#### Case-insensitive login

Set `sonar.authenticator.downcase` to `true` when delegating authentication to an LDAP/AD server which is case-insensitive.

#### Group mapping behaviour

When group mapping is configured (i.e. you manually configured `ldap.group.*` or you use the *windows authentication mode* with lightweight AD config), membership in LDAP/AD will override any membership locally configured in SonarQube. LDAP/AD becomes the one and only place to manage group membership (and the info is fetched each time the user logs in).

Comment: Thanks! That was it! A question however, how do I assign a group/role to my domain user in this case? Mapping roles and security groups in AD?

Comment: In AD: add user `foo` to group `bar` (roles are [not supported](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin#LDAPPlugin-GroupMapping)). In SonarQube: create group `bar`. When `foo` logs in SonarQube, `foo` will automatically be added to group `bar`.

Comment: I did exactly that. Also in Sonar the group bar is granted the Global permission Administer System. I expect that once I log in with foo, that foo is an administrator of Sonar. Is there any special setting in the sonar.properties I need to set to make this happen? I tried setting ldap.group.baseDn=dc=eu,dc=mydomain,dc=local but with no success. Thanks

Comment: I found out why. Group names seems to be case sensitive and do also require the domain to be specified. I also found that the best thing is to set sonar.log.level=DEBUG and then log in with a user. In the log you will see WindowsAuthenticationHelper] Groups for the user and a list of all groups of which this user is part of. Thank you for all of your suggestions! Cheers